# Groovy script code to append xml node taking 15+ hours for 6K employee records

Tags: javascript, xml, groovy, xml-parsing, sap-cloud-platform

Below code is working but taking 15+ hours to execute 6000 employee records, any improvements possible?

I have two employee record structures (employee data and employee benefits) for each of 6000 employees I have merged them into single xml using personnel number (to check the xml structure please check my previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174244/multiple-different-xml-structures-to-one-using-xml-using-xsl).

Now I have to append a node/subnode in xml employee record when ID (personIdExternal in multimap:Message1 finds same ID / PERNR in multimap:Message2.

```
 xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'EmpEmployment'}.each{ p->

 def perID = xml.'**'.find{it.personIdExternal.text() == p.personIdExternal.text()} 
 def pernr = xml.'**'.find{it.PERNR.text() == '000'+perID.personIdExternal.text()}
 if(pernr != null)
 {    
       perID.appendNode {
       erpBenEligibility(pernr.PARDT.text()) }
  }

}  
 message.setBody(groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml))
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<multimap:Message1>
<person>
 <person>
    <street>test_stree1</street>
    <city>test_city1</city>
    <state>test_state1</state>
    <EmpEmployment>
     <personIdExternal> 001 </personIdExternal>
    </EmpEmployment>
 </person>
 <person>
    <street>test_stree2</street>
    <city>test_city2</city>
    <state>test_state2</state>
     <EmpEmployment>
     <personIdExternal> 002 </personIdExternal>
    </EmpEmployment>
 </person>
 <person>
    <street>test_stree3</street>
    <city>test_city3</city>
    <state>test_state3</state>
     <EmpEmployment>
     <personIdExternal> 003</personIdExternal>
     </EmpEmployment>
 </person>
</person>
</multimap:Message1>
<multimap:Message2>
<rfc:ZHR_GET_EMP_BENEFIT_DETAILS.Response xmlns:rfc="urn:sap- 
    com:document:sap:rfc:functions"> 
 <phone>
  <home>
   <phone>number1</phone>
  </home> 
  <PERNR> 001 </PERNR>
  <PARDT>#### 1 ####</PARDT>
  <home>
   <phone>number2</phone>
  </home> 
  <PERNR> 002 </PERNR>
  <PARDT>#### 2 ####</PARDT>
  <home>
   <phone>number3</phone>
  </home> 
  <PERNR> 003 </PERNR>
  <PARDT>#### 3 ####</PARDT>
</phone> 
</rfc:ZHR_GET_EMP_BENEFIT_DETAILS.Response xmlns:rfc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">    
</multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Comment: If you can stomach the api, you could go for a faster XML library like: https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/

Comment: a lot of modifications could be done. but first - stop using `.'**'.` - better to use exact gpath (full or relative).

Comment: and your code does not correspond to your previous almost deleted question. please edit this question and add short xml sample to execute this code.

Comment: Thank you for your response @daggett . I have added sample XML example in my question, as asked in my previous question I have '</multimap:Messages> <multimap:Message1> and <multimap:Message2>' tags in my XML which not allowing me to use exact gpath so I am using '**' to traverse to the node I wanted. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: i don't see `PARDT` element in xml that is referenced from code. also i don't see any case when `it.PERNR.text() == '000'+perID.personIdExternal.text()` in your xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some major issues in your code:

- using  `.**` accessors. if you have 10000 `persons` in message1, then `xml.**` will return an array with `count(person)+count(EmpEmployment)+count(personIdExternal) = 10000*3` elements. and calling findAll on this array should scan all those elements
- inside the main loop `xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'EmpEmployment'}.each{` you are building nested large arrays for no reason. for example after this expression `def perID = xml.'**'.find{it.personIdExternal.text() == p.personIdExternal.text()}` you have `perID` equals to `p`

your code still does not correspond to the xml sample.

so, i'm going to make some assumptions to show how you could build gpath without `.**.`:

let we have xml like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<multimap:Message1>
  <person>
      <person>
        <EmpEmployment>
          <personIdExternal>001</personIdExternal>
        </EmpEmployment>
      </person>
  </person>
</multimap:Message1>
<multimap:Message2>
  <phone>
      <xyz>
        <PERNR>000001</PERNR>
        <PARDT>#### 1 ####</PARDT>
      </xyz>
  </phone>
</multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

this is a code part to build large xml message:

```javascript
def count = 60000 //just for test let's create xml with 60K elements
def msg = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<multimap:Message1>
  <person>
'''+
(1..count).collect{"""\
      <person>
        <EmpEmployment>
          <personIdExternal>${String.format('%03d',it)}</personIdExternal>
        </EmpEmployment>
      </person>
"""}.join()+
'''  </person>
</multimap:Message1>
<multimap:Message2>
  <phone>
'''+
(1..count).collect{"""\
      <xyz>
        <PERNR>${String.format('%06d',it)}</PERNR>
        <PARDT>#### ${it} ####</PARDT>
      </xyz>
"""}.join()+
'''  </phone>
</multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
'''
```

and now the modified transforming algorithm:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(msg)

def t = System.currentTimeMillis()
def ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace('http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge')

//for fast search let map PERNR value to a node that contains it
def pernrMap=xml[ns.Message2][0].phone[0].children().collectEntries{ [it.PERNR.text(), it] }

//itearte msg1 -> find entry in pernrMap -> add node
xml[ns.Message1][0].person[0].person.each{p->
    def emp = p.EmpEmployment[0]
    def pernr = pernrMap['000'+emp.personIdExternal.text()]
    if(pernr) emp.appendNode('erpBenEligibility', null, pernr.PARDT.text() )
}
groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
println "t = ${(System.currentTimeMillis()-t)/1000} sec"
```

even for 60k elements in msg1 & msg2 it does transformation in less then 1 sec.

Comment: Thank you so much @daggett, in my example to be simple I didn't give exact structure of message2 structure, it has one more name sp
`<multimap:Message2>
**<rfc:ZHR_GET_EMP_BENEFIT_DETAILS.Response xmlns:rfc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">**
subnodes as in previous exmples
 **</rfc:ZHR_GET_EMP_BENEFIT_DETAILS.Response>**
</multimap:Message2>`
I tried 
` def ns2 = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions')
def pernrMap = xml[ns.message2.ns2][0].LT_0167[0].children().collectEntries{
        [it.PERNR.text(), it]
    }`
But it did not work. please help.

Comment: Edited my sample xml to add the <rfc:> </rfc:> node in message2 block, please check.
tried different ways to access the children after <rfc:> like in my above comment and also def pernrMap = xml[ns.Message2][0].ns2[0].phone[0].children().collectEntries{         [it.PERNR.text(), it]     } where ns2 is the namespace in message2 block as in above comments. Please disregard LT_0167[0] in above comment, it is equal to phone[0]. error shows I am accessing null object as just 'xml[ns.Message2][0].phone[0].children().` doesn't work because of the "<rfc:ZHR_GET_EMP_BENEFIT.Response>" namespace node.

Comment: you have to declare another namespace in your code like this: `def rfcNs = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions')`

Comment: Thank you again. I did that but how to navigate through the message2 & name space. I did below but it didnt work.
     `def pernrMap = xml[ns.message2.rfcNs][0].phone[0].children().collectEntries{  [it.PERNR.text(), it] }` 
also tried
   `def pernrMap = xml[ns.Message2][0].rfcNs[0].phone[0].children().collectEntries{ 
     [it.PERNR.text(), it] }`
what is the right way to access PERNR after declaring rfc namespace? Please help.

Comment: `xml[ns.Message1][0][rfcNs.get("ZHR_GET_EMP_BENEFIT_DETAILS.Response")][0].phone[0]...`

Comment: if you want help please correct xml in your question: 1) xmlns can't be in closing tag. 2) `PERNR` and  `PARDT` in your question have no relation to each other all of them have the same parent - `phone`, so it's not possible to identify their relation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works. This decreased the processing time from 7 hours to 4 seconds.
Now I understand how name space works and how to navigate through the xml node a bit. Thanks again.
Do I need to mark this question as answered? Will I be able to assign points to you? I am new to this forum.

Comment: marking as an answered gives 15 points. so you are welcome to do it )

Comment: I dont see where I can mark it "answered", I only see share  edit  follow  flag options. Any how than you so much for providing solution.