# Traverse through each XML employee record in Groovy

Tags: groovy

My XML looks like is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <accountType>CMSV</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>36218</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails/>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <accountType>CMSV</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc222</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails/>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>    
    <accountType>PTOS</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc111</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>       
        <bookingAmount>176</bookingAmount>
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>      
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>      
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <accountType>PTOS</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc222</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>256</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>   
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>        
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <bookingStartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</bookingStartDate>
    <accountType>LOA</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc111</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>40</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>       
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>      
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <bookingStartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</bookingStartDate>
    <accountType>LOA</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc222</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>40</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
</TimeAccount>
```

I need to add a new node for each employee record when account Type is `PTOS` and subnode is `MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT`, I wrote below code which works for single employee record, how should I loop for all employee records.

```
def ptoNode =    xml.TimeAccount.find { it.accountType.text() == 'PTOS' }
     if(ptoNode !=null)
     {
def detailNode =    ptoNode.timeAccountDetails.TimeAccountDetail.find { it.bookingType.text() == 'MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT' }
    if(detailNode != null)
    {
        ptosHours = detailNode.bookingAmount.text()
        ptoNode.appendNode('newPTONode', null, ptosHours.toString() )
     }
     }
```

1. above code works only for 1st employee (`abc111`), how to do it for each employee node?
2. I need to add all hours (`bookingAmount`) sub nodes with booking type `EMPLOYEE_TIME` with in employee node and create node like above at employee header level, I am able to do it for one `EMPLOYEE_TIME` record (same like above) but could not recursively add all subnodes. how to achieve it?
3. How to loop through XML document at high level and detail level in groovy script?

Comment: use `findAll{...}` instead of `find{...}`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I get below error when I use findAll in place of find
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.text() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: get(int), get(int), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object), getAt(int), getAt(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Can it be possible to write a .each and then if (condition) like in loop in java 
loop (header node)
{
if (condition) //accoutType == PTOS
loop (child node)
{
if (condition) //booking type == EMPLOYEE_TIME
}
above is possible in groovy? if yes, could you please share how?

Comment: find "question is answered" button to get next answer ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526399/groovy-script-code-to-append-xml-node-taking-15-hours-for-6k-employee-records

Comment: I still can't see "question is answered" button on that previous question :) sorry.
May be with this discussion it will show up :)

Comment: finally, with the help of blog I answered previous thread. I had to click grayed out check mark beside your answer.
Could you please answer current question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def xml=new XmlParser().parseText('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <accountType>CMSV</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>36218</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails/>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <accountType>CMSV</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc222</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails/>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>    
    <accountType>PTOS</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc111</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>       
        <bookingAmount>176</bookingAmount>
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>      
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>      
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <accountType>PTOS</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc222</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>256</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>   
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>        
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <bookingStartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</bookingStartDate>
    <accountType>LOA</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc111</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>40</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>        
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
      <TimeAccountDetail>       
        <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>       
      </TimeAccountDetail>      
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
  <TimeAccount>
    <bookingStartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</bookingStartDate>
    <accountType>LOA</accountType>
    <bookingEndDate>2021-12-31T00:00:00.000</bookingEndDate>
    <userId>abc222</userId>
    <timeAccountDetails>
      <TimeAccountDetail>
        <bookingAmount>40</bookingAmount>        
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
      </TimeAccountDetail>
    </timeAccountDetails>
  </TimeAccount>
</TimeAccount>
''')


xml.TimeAccount.findAll{it.accountType.text()=='PTOS'}.each{ptoNode->
    ptoNode.timeAccountDetails.TimeAccountDetail.find{ it.bookingType.text() == 'MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT' }?.with{detailNode->
       ptosHours = detailNode.bookingAmount.text()
       ptoNode.appendNode('newPTONode', null, ptosHours )
    }
}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: Thank you @daggett, that worked perfectly. what is the use of "?.with" in place of ".each"? 
I will mark this question answered shortly.

Comment: `getX().with{x-> x.f1() }` the same as `x = getX(); x.f1(); `, `getX()?.with{x-> x.f1() }`  the same as `x = getX(); if(x){ x.f1(); }`. `with:` https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with(groovy.lang.Closure)   `safe access:` https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator

Comment: Thank yo so much.